# PHP - Replace Tabbed whitespace with preg replace?

Tags: php, sql-server, preg-replace

I have a form which currently accepts a tabbled white space "    " for example. I only want to allow one space between words.

Currently it looks like this:

```
preg_replace ("#[^0-9a-z]#i", " ",$string);
```

Remember I need to allow only one space at a time, How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Replace multiple whitespaces with a single space

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s\s+/',' ', $string);
```